# Apply pagination and data filtering in html grid

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, odoo-16

I have downloaded a bootstrap template for e-commerce that I want to integrate in odoo Qweb templating. In products grid view there is non functional pagination and products filtering parameters, that I want to make functional using isotope grid.

In image I have marked the filters to apply.

Code for products grid on which I want to apply pagination and products filtration.

```
<div t-attf-class="isotope-grid filter-grid cols-3 rows-1 mb-2" itemsPerPageDefault="6">
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <!-- Product-->
    <t t-foreach="Products" t-as="prods">
        <div t-attf-class="grid-item scid{{prods.product_sub_cat_id.id}} cid{{prods.product_type_id.id}} brid{{prods.product_brand_id.id}}">
            <div class="product-card">
                <div class="product-badge text-danger">
                    <t t-esc="prods.discount" />
                    % Off
                </div>
                <a class="product-thumb" t-attf-href="/template/shop-single/{{slug(prods)}}">
                    <img t-att-src="image_data_uri(prods.first_image)" style="height: 200px;" alt="Product" />
                </a>
                <h3 class="product-title">
                    <a t-attf-href="/template/shop-single/{{slug(prods)}}">
                        <t t-esc="prods.name" />
                    </a>
                </h3>
                <h4 class="product-price">
                    <del>
                        pkr
                        <t t-esc="prods.price" />
                    </del>
                    pkr
                    <t t-esc="prods.price - ((prods.discount*prods.price)/100)" />
                </h4>
                <div class="product-buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm btn-wishlist" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Whishlist">
                        <i class="icon-heart"></i>
                    </button>


                    <form t-attf-id="fa{{prods.id}}" t-attf-action="/template/update-mycart" class="d-inline-block" method="GET">
                        <input type="hidden" t-attf-id="ia{{prods.id}}" t-att-name="product_id" t-attf-value="{{prods.id}}" title="" />
                    </form>
                    <a t-attf-id="{{prods.id}}" onclick="addCart(this)" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toast="" data-toast-type="success" data-toast-position="topRight" data-toast-icon="icon-circle-check" data-toast-title="Product" data-toast-message="successfuly added to cart!">
                            Add to Cart
                        </a>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </t>
</div>
```

[filters want to apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIXAV.png)